# How can I get custom routes inside sonata admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I configure knp menu inside sonata admin product class and I want to add link to another admin class (category)

my code is:

```
protected function configureSideMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null)
{
   $menu->addChild(
        $this->trans('product.sidemenu.link_designer', array(), 'm2m'),
        array('uri' => $admin->generateUrl('sonata.classification.admin.category.list'))
    );
}
```

Unfortunatly route 'sonata.classification.admin.category.show' doesn't exist. Routes from app/console router debug also desnt work. I have no access to inject @router in servies becouse definition of service is inside vendors.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found simple solution. I was mistake because default menu item defined in sonata demo looks like this:

```
$menu->addChild(
            $this->trans('product.sidemenu.view_variations'),
            array('uri' => $admin->generateUrl('sonata.product.admin.product.variation.list', array('id' => $id)))
        );
```

And to add custom routes I had to added route parameter instead uri.

```
$menu->addChild(
            $this->trans('product.sidemenu.view_variations'),
            array('route' => 'admin_sonata_classification_category_list' )
        );
```

Now everything work .

Answer (score 2):

In your admin, you can override the `configureRoutes` method, as demonstrated in the documentation:

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/routing.html#create-a-route

This will allow you to add custom routes for your admin.

Comment: I thought that i dont need to create new route, because I wanted to use existed route. This was the reson why i didn't tryed your solution before

Comment: @user2482094 Have you tried using underscores instead of periods for the routes? Sonata uses underscores for route names.

Comment: Yes I tried.When I add underscore sonata route name I recived exception: Route doesnt exist. I digded in vendor config ( admin.xml) and I had access only to route from services which are define in config like sonata.product.admin.product.variation